# How to classify ARFF file with no labels using a trained Random Forest model?

Tags: java, machine-learning, random-forest, weka, image-segmentation

I have a training and test ARFF file dataset as such. I had created the below dataset by extracting region-of-interest from a 6 band image and the labels pertaining to each coordinate.

```
@RELATION agricultural.data

@attribute band0 numeric
@attribute band1 numeric
@attribute band3 numeric
@attribute band4 numeric
@attribute band5 numeric
@attribute band6 numeric
@attribute class {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

@data
-10.95659,-7.61896,-9.8674499,-9.118701,-8.620638,-12.699167,5
...
-9.172866,-9.814803,-10.693634,-13.313326,-8.568673,-12.355089,3
```

Using the above data I have trained the RandomForest and have gotten some results which seem in-line with what I expect.

---

I have an ARFF file dataset as such. It doesn't have any class attribute

```
@RELATION agricultural.data.fullimage

@attribute band0 numeric
@attribute band1 numeric
@attribute band3 numeric
@attribute band4 numeric
@attribute band5 numeric
@attribute band6 numeric

@data
-9.261405,-7.302625,-10.753542,-8.018068,-7.776727,-12.878252
...
-9.188496,-10.676176,-14.194083,-9.687324,-9.785445,-12.490084
```

This is actual image line-by-line generated ARFF file. I want to classify the whole image. It doesn't have any labels. How do I classify the image. (Segmentation?)

```
FilteredClassifier fc = new FilteredClassifier();
fc.setClassifier(myRandomForestTrainedModel);

for(int pixel=0;pixel < ncols;pixel++) {
    double prediction;
    /**Some edge case handling**/
    prediction = fc.classifyInstance(data.instance(pixel)); //Each data here is a row in the image which I create an ARFF file for
    byteLinePrediction[pixel] = (byte)Math.floor(prediction+0.5);
}
```

There is an exception at the `classifyInstance()` function which reads as  below:

```
weka.core.UnassignedClassException: weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier: Class attribute not set!
```

But, I don't have classes assigned to these pixels as I don't want to evaluate the performance of the classifier but use the classifier to generate an classified(segmented) image map.

Answer (score 1):

The data that you use for making predictions needs to have the **exact same format** as the training data, including the class attribute (Weka may query at prediction time possible class values). That attribute must also be flagged as class attribute (`setClassIndex(...)`).

However, all actual values in the data section can be missing ('?').

You can use the [Add](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Add.html) filter to append the class attribute to your test data, including the required nominal labels.

Comment: So I dump placeholder values? And use the prediction as used in evaluation of test dataset. I was exactly trying that after I posted this question. I did not get output. I'll let you know if I work it out.

Comment: `classifyInstance` returns the **index** of the label. Use the [value(int)](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/Attribute.html#value-int-) method of your class attribute to determine the label string (casting the double to an int).